# SQL Query (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

Please advise how to achieve below ask in PostgreSQL query

Input

```
Column_x
null
null
1257-1;1258-3;1235-4;111-1
1260-3
1263-6;1457-1
null
null
```

Basically, need to count of id's

Expected output

```
Column_x 
0
0
4 (Count of Id's)
1
2
0
0
```

Since I'm new to SQL, did not find much help on internet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take it the column type is text/varchar? If so this code should do it:

```
SELECT
    Column_x,
    COALESCE(ARRAY_LENGTH(STRING_TO_ARRAY(Column_x, ';'), 1), 0) AS id_count
FROM table_name;
```

And some explanation - reading the parenthesis from inner-most:

- `STRING_TO_ARRAY(Column_x, ';')` takes the text field and turns it into array, using ";" as a delimiter.
- `ARRAY_LENGTH(array, 1)` returns the number of elements in the array.
- `COALESCE(int, 0)` is here, because the null rows will return a count of null, so we use coalesce to make them "0"

Comment: This solution worked as expected. Thanks for your help and explanation

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `regexp_split_to_table` to split a string into a table, then use `group by` and `count` to count the ids :

```
select t.column_x, coalesce(_count, 0)
from mytable t
left join (
  select column_x, count(*) as _count
  from mytable
  cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(Column_x, ';') AS t(x)
  group by column_x
) as s on s.column_x = t.column_x
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/19VLkBY-)